# Google Contacts API 401 Authorization Required

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I am making the following request to the Google Contacts API after obtaining a oauth2 token.

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com/full?access_token=' + authData.authorizationCode + '&alt=json',
         dataType: "jsonp",
         success:function(data) {
                    console.log((data));
                }
            });
```

This produces the following GET HTTP request:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com/full?access_token=4/95N2f8xA1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXQC3BtuuMbk.Aug-7c4GLLMZXmXvfARQvtgU5IVtmgI&alt=json&callback=jQuery111XXXXX1426XXX03&_=1431142848004
```

However google responds back with **Status Code:401 Authorization required**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI I was using the authorization code and not the access token to request for the contact details. Hence why I was getting the error

Diagram here illustrates the oauth2 flow:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

This is a great resource for seeing what your code should actually be doing:
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Here is a comprehensive example of using googles oauth2 for api's:
http://www.9bitstudios.com/2013/05/using-oauth-2-0-for-google-apis/

Below code gets the list of emails contacts

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json',
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {'access_token': authData.authorizationToken.access_token},
                    success:function(data) {
                        var entryOfEmails = data.feed.entry;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                                console.log(entryOfEmails[i].gd$email[0].address);
                            }
                    }
                 });
```

Comment: i am getting the same error ....where have you added access token ? can you please provide code snippet ... i am trying for hours..